# codeigniter array passing in views and string comparision

Tags: php, codeigniter, strcmp

I am using cibonfire and I am using their template. This is my code in my view page:

```
<?php
        Template::block(
            $block_name = 'leftsidebar',
            $default_view = 'leftsidebar',              
            $data = array( 'role' => $role[0]->role_name)
        );
?>
```

In my template I am doing this :

```
<?php if(strcmp($role['role_name'], "Bimalogy Admin") == 0 ): ?>
    <h4><u><b>User Control</b></u></h4>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is showing `Undefined index: role_name` error.

If I am doing this in my template :

```
<?php if(strcmp($data['role'], "Bimalogy Admin") == 0 ): ?>
<h4><u><b>User Control</b></u></h4>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Showing `Undefined variable: data`

If I `echo $role` its displaying `Array` as an output.

My question is how to access that array in this template and compare it with string.

Comment: try to `print_r($role)` you'll see array structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to dump the `$role` array with `var_dump($role)`.

Depending on how the array is built, you may need to use `$role->role_name`, or `$role[0]->role_name`, or `$role[0]['role_name']` etc.